# USB drive with stripped down Ubuntu

Tags: live-usb, custom-distributions

Is there a proper way to set up a flash drive with a stripped down version of Ubuntu (any version) leaving the user with an OS and a browser only?

Comment: Please read [How to customize live Ubuntu CD?](http://askubuntu.com/q/48535/159545), in particular notice the use of [Ubuntu Builder](https://code.google.com/p/ubuntu-builder/).

Answer (score 0):

How to setup Ubuntu with a web browser, and no pre-installs:

1. Download Ubuntu 13.04 - Server X86-64
   http://releases.ubuntu.com/raring/ubuntu-13.04-server-amd64.iso (or you can download the 32-bit version if you prefer)
2. Burn the ISO to a DVD
3. Boot the DVD and begin the installation process
4. When you get to a list of software to install, choose "manual package selection"
5. After installing Ubuntu Server, boot it up
6. In the terminal type: `sudo apt-get install xfce4` , this will install xfce desktop environment. If you prefer you can install unity, gnome, kde, mate, or something else.
7. In the terminal type: `sudo apt-get install gdm`, this will install gnome display manager (aka your login screen), if you prefer you can install something else, like kdm, or lightdm.
8. In the terminal type: `sudo halt -p`, this will shut down the computer
9. Turn the computer on, and login, now install the web browser you want.

The size will vary depending on which desktop environment and desktop manager you install, but you will be looking around the 2400-2600 MB mark excluding temporary files.

**PLEASE NOTE:** There will be a few things preinstalled, like a terminal emulator so you can install other programs, and a file manager, but nothing major. You will see a menu entry called *web browser*, but there is no web browser installed until you install one.

**PLEASE NOTE:** If you decide to install a desktop environment other than XFCE, make sure the command you use is going to install just the desktop environment and not the full package that includes other recommended software.

**PLEASE NOTE:** If you prefer to not use the terminal to install software you can install the Ubuntu Software Center by typing: `sudo apt-get install software-center`.

<sup>**Source:** http://candlelight.any.djun.net/x/1/index.php?topic=586.0</sup>